# Export Sql Server 2008 database into MS Access Database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, export

I want to export Sql Server 2008 table objects into MS Access database . I try to find it but not got any perfect way to solve the given problem. Please suggest what should i do.

Answer (score 4):

You can do in from Import Wizard from an MS Access file

1. Create a MS Access database.
2. Go to the **External Data** tab Import & link Section.
3. Make an **ODBC Database** connection with SQL database
4. Import tables(consider excluding schema and system tables if you do not need them)

Answer (score 2):

follow this step to export to ms acess:

1. Right click on your database -> Task -> Export Data
2. Choose your data source and database
3. Click on next choose your destination database in destination combo select ms Access Database select file of Access
   database
4. Click next: copy data from tables or views...
5. Click next: select all tables
6. Click next
7. Click finish

   [image: Screenshot of choose access database export]

Username & password must be blank

Comment: Thank. I am getting error unrecognized data base format at the time of select ms Access Database.  Second think its also have text box for User ID and Password in time of selection ms Access Database.